# Why so little voting?

Tags: discussion

I see many questions and answers with a vote score of zero, even after years. (I see this on other SE sites also.) Sometimes I see -1 scores, so I know people are downvoting. But why don't they vote early and often? I do. If I even read something, I almost always upvote. (It makes it easy to see what I have read before.)

Is there some reason people don't vote? It can't be inexperience, because I see questions and answers and comments by experienced people.

Comment: Sometimes I see that all early answers to a question are downvoted, and I suspect that the OP did so, because they *didn't like* the answers.

Comment: Someone upvoted... 9 others did not. You know who you are! Ha ha

Comment: I try to upvote questions that are clearly presented and seem relevant to serious philosophy, but I've noticed that my +1's are often downvoted back to 0. Not sure what to make of that. I would prefer to see reasonable questions be upvoted.

Comment: Well if there's a net amount of people attempting to troll by blindly down voting then it doesn't actually make a difference to the site really, because the questions will still get the same amount of traction if they're all exploited proportionally. The only problem would be people coming on here, seeing the low votes and thinking "wow noone uses this site im going to go now byebye" and leaves because of that reason.

Comment: @AshtonDowling Well, I think the low vote scores kept me away from PhilSE for years before I had finally worked through the other interesting sites and had nowhere else to go. A very low traffic site like Computer Science Edicators gets much higher vote scores. Maybe it is the paradox that more observers result in inaction? "Someone else will do it." But other high traffic sites have much more voting. Philosophers, can't live with em, can't think without em.

Comment: No one chided me for my practice of: "upvote everything you read so you can tell later on that you already saw it." It is how I navigate the masses of material here over years of time. Maybe SE should have a seen-this indicator?

Comment: I appreciate this mindset, coming from a network with the same issue. One legitimate reason is not wanting to vote on what you've not reviewed, and review takes time and energy. But there are also plenty illegitimate reasons... hopefully less here.